# All possible measures on the rationals

Tags: measure-theory, rational-numbers

I want to determine all possible measures on the measurable space $(\mathbb{Q},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{Q}))$. I know that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{Q})=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$.

I really have no idea on how to start but writing down the trivial measures. Thank you for any help or hint in advance.

Comment: Since $\mathbb Q$ is countable, a measure $\mu$ is entirely defined by the value on singletons $\mu(\{x\})$ for $x\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: You probably mean $|\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{Q})|=|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})|$  They are not equal as sets, but they do have the same cardinality.

Comment: Thanks. Why are they not equal @RossMillikan, I thought $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ for any $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on $X$?

Comment: @RossMillikan Aren't they equal? As long as $\mathcal B(\mathbb Q)$ contains the singletons, it must contain every subset of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @RossMillikan No, it is actual equality - the Borel sets in $\mathbb Q$ are all subsets of $\mathbb Q$. But I almost posted the same comment before realizing this :)